# SQL LENGTH in ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails

How can I translate this MySQL's WHERE to ActiveRecord :condition?

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE LENGTH(users.last_name) < 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["LENGTH(last_name) < ?", 3])
```

or you can use [find_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001781)

```
 User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE LENGTH(users.last_name) < 3")
```